# How do I refrain from showing repeat datetime data in a django template forloop?

Tags: django, django-templates

In a django template, I'm accessing objects in a list filtered by the objects' `datetime`.

Here's a current image of the `object_list` onto an HTML table:
[image: table_of_datetime_objects]

The *time* part of the `datetime` ("11:50a.m") must remain regardless of duplicates.
However, the *date* part of the `datetime` ("September 9"), must appear only once for each unique date.

Essentially, what I'm looking for would look something like:
[image: edited_table]

How would I go about achieving this effect? I've tried using `{% if forloop.first %}`, but I'm unable to find a way to target all "firsts" of unique dates.

This is the current code which corresponds to the first image:

```
{% for event in object_list %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ event.datetime|date:"F j g:ia e" }}: </td>
  <td><a href="{% url 'detail' event.id %}">{{ event.venue }}</a></td>
</tr>  
{% endfor %}
```

I've also considered not using the *date* of the `datetime` object and manually coding the dates in the HTML, but wouldn't know how to eventually tie the DOM date to the `object_list` according to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what the [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag is for.

I would split your output into two parts, and use ifchanged on the date only.

```
<tr>
  <td>{% ifchanged %}{{ event.datetime|date:"F j" }}{% endifchanged %}</td>
  <td>{{ event.datetime|date:"g:ia e" }}: </td>
  <td><a href="{% url 'detail' event.id %}">{{ event.venue }}</a></td>
</tr>
```